# Unable to change button colour, event script not executing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are other ways around this, I'm more looking for an explanation of why this isn't working. I am trying to implement a quiz, the first section is multiple choice. When the correct answer is clicked I want the button to turn green, if any of the incorrect buttons are clicked I want them to turn red. I've checked the code on the validator and there doesn't appear to be any mistakes yet the buttons are still not interactive. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here please?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Trivia!</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                let incorrects = document.querySelectorAll(".incorrect_answer");
                incorrects.addEventListener('click', function() {
                let clicked = event.srcElement;
                clicked.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            });
                let correct = document.querySelector(".correct_answer");
                correct.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    correct.style.backgoundColor = 'green';
            });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Trivia!</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
                <hr>
                <h3>How many species of Dolphin are there?</h3>
                    <button class="correct_answer">42</button>
                    <button class="incorrect_answer">53</button>
                    <button class="incorrect_answer">24</button>
                    <button class="incorrect_answer">11</button>
            </div>

            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
                <hr>
                <!-- TODO: Add free response question here use input tags -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are getting errors in the console, you didn't even open the dev tools
2. You can't use `addEventListener` on list of items
3. You are referencing `event` variable that doesn't exist
4. You had a typo in `backgroundColor`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let incorrects = document.querySelectorAll(".incorrect_answer");
  incorrects.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let clicked = event.srcElement;
    clicked.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }));
  let correct = document.querySelector(".correct_answer");
  correct.addEventListener('click', function() {
    correct.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Trivia!</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="section">
      <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
      <hr>
      <h3>How many species of Dolphin are there?</h3>
      <button class="correct_answer">42</button>
      <button class="incorrect_answer">53</button>
      <button class="incorrect_answer">24</button>
      <button class="incorrect_answer">11</button>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
      <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
      <hr>
      <!-- TODO: Add free response question here use input tags -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh damn, thanks! How do I open dev tools on VScode? Sorry, pretty new to this...

Comment: `F12` in the browser

Comment: if you are using Chrome, do VIew->Developer->Developer tools

Comment: [Global `event` is a thing.](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-window-event)